# Is there a term for speaking to oneself in the second person?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, terminology, obscure-terms

A recent [article in Aeon](https://aeon.co/ideas/why-speaking-to-yourself-in-the-third-person-makes-you-wiser) noted that "illeism" is a term for speaking about oneself in the third person. The article argues that adopting this rhetorical stance can aid in thinking through issues:

> ...The scientific research suggests that you should adopt an ancient rhetorical method favoured by the likes of Julius Caesar and known as ‘illeism’ – or speaking about yourself in the third person... If I was considering an argument that I’d had with a friend, for instance, I might start by silently thinking to myself: "David felt frustrated that…" The idea is that this small change in perspective can clear your emotional fog, allowing you to see past your biases.

Is there a similar term for talking through a problem with oneself in the *second* person? (Adapting the example above, "*You* are feeling frustrated that...")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't as old a term as "illeism," as I understand, but [this article](https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/08/smarter-living/benefits-of-talking-to-yourself-self-talk.html) and [this article](https://www.nbcnews.com/better/health/talking-yourself-normal-here-s-how-master-it-ncna918091) both use the phrase "self-talk" for self-directed second-person speech in a similar context as the Aeon article quoted above.

Comment: George Costanza says "George is getting thirsty!"